# cannot connect via expo app, something went wrong network response timed out. React Native

Tags: react-native, expo, npx

Am new to react native and trying to start a server using npx expo start command.
It starts up fine and shows the qr code but when I scan it with my phone its showing network response timed out.

I double checked am on same wifi on my computer as well as on my phone,
I tried to start using tunnel but even that is giving me the same error.

how to fix this error? Also is there a way to connect to this server manually with a usb cable?

Comment: I face this problem occasionally. What works for me is just disconnected these internet connection from both and reconnecting after waiting a few seconds. You can also try clearing your cache with npx expo start -c